# How can I precisely set my mouse location for tools which use it?

Tags: 3d-view, 3d-cursor, mouse, tools

I'm learning the [bend tool](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/meshes/editing/mesh/transform/bend.html). It works by having you start with two points in space. One of them is the 3D cursor, and the other is your mouse cursor. The line that connects determines what your geometry bends around.

I can precisely position the 3D cursor with `3D Viewport > Sidebar > View > 3D Cursor`, so I'm good there.

But I can't figure out how I could be exact about my mouse's location. For example, if I want to start bending along the Z axis from `Z=1.0` to `Z=2.0`, I can get the 3D cursor to `Z=1.0` but I can only get my mouse approximately at `Z=2.0` by using one of the orthographic views. I can be closer if I zoom in, but then I might not be able to see the area I need to in order to express the bend I want. And even if I zoom in as far as I can, it still wouldn't be perfect.

What I'd really like is a second 3D cursor. Am I missing something? Is there a way to perfectly position the mouse so I can be precise when using tools like bend?

Comment: You might want to use the simple deform modifier set to bend. There you can use another object as an origin for the deformation, not relying on the pointer position. I think you have the same settings if not more with the modifier